# How can i clone MAC address on Windows like i can on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, windows-10, ubuntu, wireless-networking, mac-address

Recently i bought a new laptop, with a Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter. My old laptop had an AR9285.

Let's say that my old laptop's MAC was B7:AA:BB:CC:DD.
My new laptop has the C9:AA:BB:CC:DD.

Now, i want to use my old NICs MAC on my new one.

I tried to change it in Windows, with programs, but I couldn't use the B7:AA:BB:CC:DD scheme, I could only use 0E:AA:BB:CC:DD and so on.

I also tried it on Ubuntu, where there is an option, to type in a cloned MAC address. This worked there well, my router show, that i had the MAC that i wanted.

Is there any way to do the same on Windows?

Comment: You should NOT do this. In fact, you CANNOT on Windows for a wifi card, except to certain addresses. Why do you want to? I cannot stress enough that you shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to natively change you wireless nic's mac is to edit it in the adapter settings.

1. Open `Network and Sharing Center`, choose `Change Adapter Settings` on the left.
2. Right click on your wireless adapter and choose `properties`.
3. Make sure the `Networking` tab is selected (should be by default) and choose `Configure`.
4. Click the `Advanced` tab.
5. In the `Property` window, choose `Network Address` and insert your desired mac.
6. Disable/Reenable adapter.